# Drupal 7 - How do I cache / gzip a webform page?

Tags: 7, webforms, caching, performance

I have my frontpage as a webform and want to know how I can provide compression to this page as drupal does not cache/gzip a webform page due to the forms. What are some possible solutions to this?

Comment: Are you using HoneyPot or another CAPTCHA method?  They do sometimes interfere with cachability of webforms.

Comment: yes i do believe i have that loaded. wouldn't a ajax form load solve this issue?